# Null pointer exception while using SWT Bot Generator in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I am trying to use SWT Bot generator in eclipse but as soon as i say start recording i get a null pointer exception, here is the exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-10-17 10:44:19.659
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.generator.ui.RecorderDialog$4.handleCodeGenerated(RecorderDialog.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.generator.ui.BotGeneratorEventDispatcher.dispatchCodeGenerated(BotGeneratorEventDispatcher.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.generator.ui.BotGeneratorEventDispatcher.processRules(BotGeneratorEventDispatcher.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.generator.ui.BotGeneratorEventDispatcher.handleEvent(BotGeneratorEventDispatcher.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.closeWidget(Decorations.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_CLOSE(Decorations.java:1694)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4530)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

It was working once but it crashed all of a sudden and now the above mentioned error!
I am also using **-Dorg.eclipse.swtbot.generator.enable=true** option in arguments of run configuration. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this was the only option, may be i was missing something, but finally i used the following repo: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/snapshots/#sthash.zMmLuzVs.dpuf 
I got this from: http://planet.jboss.org/post/what_s_hot_for_swtbot
Well this worked for me.
Thanks @greg-449 for the info, it helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

This Eclipse bug seems to match your error: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416011. The bug talks about using SWTBOT with palette widgets.

Comment: yup you are right i used a different repo : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/snapshots/#sthash.zMmLuzVs.dpuf